# Is slice_max(n=0) not possible?

Tags: r

I'm doing

```
df_sliced <- df %>% group_by(group) %>% slice_max(n=0, order_by=n, with_ties = FALSE)
```

but it's just ignored.
Meaning, the df_sliced is equal df.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?  Returning 0 rows from each group?

Comment: Are you expecting `df` to change when you make a calculation that starts with it? I can run `mtcars |> group_by(gear) |> slice_max(order_by = mpg, n = 0)` and get a zero-row data frame as the output, as I'd expect. In my example, I'd need to assign the output back to `mtcars` if I wanted it to change.

Comment: `n` according to the docs: `Provide either n, the number of rows, or prop, the proportion of rows to select. If neither are supplied, n = 1 will be used.`

Comment: As @JonSpring points out, you need to *assign* the object returned by the pipe to `df` if you want to change its value.  Voting to close as a typo.  I believe `df <- df %>% filter(FALSE)` is a more concise route to the same result.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen yes, seems strange but I have an interface where users can select how much they want. if they place a 0 there they won't receive any results. so df needs to have the columns group and n but no rows.

Comment: I suspect you're running into the issue where choosing a negative `n` drops that many rows instead of keeping them.  I assume it's therefore treating 0 as "drop no rows" instead of "keep no rows".  I think @Limey's comment should show one way (using `filter(FALSE)`) even though you've clarified the assignment issue was not the cause.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with the assignment to `n` inside `slice_max()`.

For example

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% slice_max(n=0, order_by=n, with_ties=FALSE)
Error in `slice_max()`:
! Problem while computing indices.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: cyl = 4.
Caused by error:
! `order_by` must be a vector, not a function.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

and

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% add_column(n=0) %>% slice_max(n)
# A tibble: 32 × 12
# Groups:   cyl [3]
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb     n
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  22.8     4 108      93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1     0
 2  24.4     4 147.     62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2     0
 3  22.8     4 141.     95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2     0
 4  32.4     4  78.7    66  4.08  2.2   19.5     1     1     4     1     0
 5  30.4     4  75.7    52  4.93  1.62  18.5     1     1     4     2     0
 6  33.9     4  71.1    65  4.22  1.84  19.9     1     1     4     1     0
 7  21.5     4 120.     97  3.7   2.46  20.0     1     0     3     1     0
 8  27.3     4  79      66  4.08  1.94  18.9     1     1     4     1     0
 9  26       4 120.     91  4.43  2.14  16.7     0     1     5     2     0
10  30.4     4  95.1   113  3.77  1.51  16.9     1     1     5     2     0
# … with 22 more rows
```

but

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% add_column(n=0) %>% slice_max(n, with_ties=FALSE)
# A tibble: 3 × 12
# Groups:   cyl [3]
    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb     n
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  22.8     4   108    93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1     0
2  21       6   160   110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4     0
3  18.7     8   360   175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2     0
```

suggesting that

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% add_column(n=0) %>% head(0)
# A tibble: 0 × 12
# Groups:   cyl [0]
# … with 12 variables: mpg <dbl>, cyl <dbl>, disp <dbl>, hp <dbl>, drat <dbl>, wt <dbl>, qsec <dbl>, vs <dbl>, am <dbl>,
#   gear <dbl>, carb <dbl>, n <dbl>
```

(or `mtcars %>% add_column(n=0) %>% head(0)`)

is a potential solution.

Comment: FWIW, using a dev version of dplyr 1.0.99.9000 does not produce the first error for me.

Comment: @JonSpring Interesting.  I have 1.0.10.  Old, I know...